# Pausing print queues via powershell/wmi

Tags: powershell, printing, wmi, spooler

I am trying to pause all queues on a 2003 print server and the following which works on a 2008R2 and 2012R2 server does not work on the 2003 print server. Is there an equivalent WMI call that I can use on the 2003 server?

```
$strComputer = "test" Get-WmiObject win32printer -ComputerName $strComputer | % {$null = $.pause()}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Get-WmiObject : Generic failure At line:1 char:1 + Get-WmiObject win32printer -ComputerName $strComputer | % {$null = $.pause()} + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + 
CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: try with `$_.pause()`

Comment: That did not work either.  Even getting a list of printers works on 2008r2/2012r2 but not on the 2003 r2 server:

$printserver = "stest" 
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_Printer -computer $printserver | Select Name,DriverName,PortName | Export-CSV -path 'E:\printers.csv'

Comment: Ah yes, it's actually the Get-WmiObject that has an issue (the pause issue would have come later)...try with  Get-WmiObject win32_printer

Comment: It was the spooler service.  Once i restarted it, everything worked.  Thanks!